# Getting HTML response instead of Json while calling rest API via Ruby

Tags: json, ruby, rest, api

I am calling API via Ruby but it give me HTML response instead of JSON. When I call the same api via POSTMAN it give correct json response. My code and postman screen shoot has attached.

```
require 'net/https'
require 'json'

uri = URI('https://www.mobifinplus.com/api.php')
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
http.use_ssl = true
http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
req = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.path, 'Content-Type' => 'text/json')
req.body = '
{"request_type" : "registration", "first_name" : "test", "last_name" : "test", "country_code_mobile" : "+254", "mobile_no" : "1234567", "id_number" : "1234", "username" : "weratest", "password" : "test", "gender" : "male", "pinnumber" : "1234"}'

  res = http.request(req)
    puts "response #{res.message}"
    puts "response #{res.body}"
```

[image]

Comment: try content type `application/json`,  `req = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.path, 'Content-Type' => 'application/json')`

Comment: I did but same result.

Comment: It must be a headers issue. Post the headers from both requests.